# nvarchar datatype displays question marks in php echo

Tags: php, sql-server, nvarchar

I am using sqlsrv_* mssql drivers for php to connect to sql server database and am reading an `nvarchar` field named `uniname1` from the table which holds Indian regional language characters. All is well until I try to print the `nvarchar` field now in php associative array and it displays all `?????????` (question marks).

Please see the code below

```
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r(($row['uniname1'])); exit;
```

I am using php version 5.4.16. and sql server2008. I have tried using meta tags utf8, mb encoding, everything, but nothing helped.

Please help me get to display the regional language on web screen from the database

Answer (score 0):

Not the problem of SQL Server if you can see the correct characters in the database. Reconfigure your web server to support UTF-8 encoding.

Assuming you have Apache as your Web Server and PHP, you need to:

> **Apache**

- Browse to the `httpd.conf` file then find `AddDefaultCharset`. If it exists, change the value to `utf-8`

> **PHP**

- Browse to the `php.ini` file then find `default_charset`. Change it to `utf-8`

Comment: But it's not working.Is there any other way to solve this?